# JAVA ObjectNode get in JSON array

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a JSON that I get with ObjectNode.

However, I can not get the ID of the object "LibellePrerequis"
Is the method used the right one?

if I do :

> String libelleprerequis = objectNode.get("id").asText();

I have the id of the script

```
{
"script":{
"id":2,
"name_script":"tes",
"libellePrerequis": {"id":3, "name_libelle":"Soc contrat VAM"}
}
```

My controller :

```
    @PostMapping("/create")
        public ResponseEntity<Script> updateScriptLibellePrerequis(@RequestBody ObjectNode objectNode) {
            String libelleprerequis = objectNode.get("libellePrerequis.id").asText();
            System.out.println("Libelle Prerequis with ID = " + libelleprerequis + "...");
}
```

error :

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
>   [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: Your id is a numeric value. You try to get it asText. Is this correct?

Comment: i try to make asInt and asLong  .. and i try libellePrerequis.name_libelle with asText and same error

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: i can do : objectNode.get("id").asText();  but I get the id of the script, but when i want id of libelleprerequis I get the error

Comment: try objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").get("id").asText() as this should return objectNode.get("libellePrerequis") JsonNode Object

Comment: Thank you @ManojKrishna it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `objectNode.get("libellePrerequis").get("id").asText()` as this should return objectNode.get("libellePrerequis")is a JsonNode Object